# How to invert Differences[list, order] with order >1?

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-difference-method

`Differences` order 1 can be invert using `FoldList[]`, but does not work with higher orders. For Example

```
Differences[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, 3]
```

> ```
> {-a + 3 b - 3 c + d, -b + 3 c - 3 d + e, -c + 3 d - 3 e + f, -d +  3 e - 3 f + g}
> ```

this case `FoldList` does not work.

Comment: What's your purpose? You should realize that any such inversion of order n will generally differ from the original data by an arbitrary polynomial of order n-1.

Comment: It is only for an educational purpose. To make an analysis of basic time series, autoregressive or moving average (ignoring ARMA, SARMA, SARIMA, etc.), the seasonality is filtered using differences.

Comment: One way to approach this is to recognize that the Differences is a moving average filter, The inverse of a moving average filter is an autoregressive filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the original list uniquely, you need to  provide the initial `n` values of the input list (`lst`). The following function "invert"s `Differences[lst, n]` using three arguments: a list of differences, the difference order (`n`) and the values of the first `n`  elements of the list to be recovered.

```
ClearAll[invertDifferences]
invertDifferences = Module[{vars = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]]& /@ Range[#2], fold, inits},
    fold = Fold[FoldList[Plus, #2, #] &, #, vars]; 
    inits = Solve[Thread[fold[[;; #2]] == #3], vars][[1]]; 
    Simplify[fold /. inits]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
lst = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
invertDifferences[Differences[lst, 3], 3, {a, b, c}]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}

```
invertDifferences[Differences[lst, 2], 2, {a, b}]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}

```
invertDifferences[Differences[Range[15], 4], 4, Range[4]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}